# jQuery if url:contains not conditioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simply display a RSS feed only if the user is on a certain page, I would like to use if `url:contains` due to how my site is built. But currently it's displaying my feed regardless and doesn't seem to be checking my if statement of `url:contains` correctly.

```
jQuery(function($) {

var url = location.pathname;

  if ("url:contains('movies')") {
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }
....
```

Comment: `url.indexOf('movies') > -1`

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what that does a little further. Is it checking full URL or only ending etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because is `"url:contains('movies')"` is string, there are no functions there. It's a string which is true logically. Therefore, making the condition always truthy. Use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

```
// Whether the URL contains movies at beginning, middle or end. 
if (url.indexOf('movies') > -1) { 
   // Rest of move
}
```

Example: condition met

```js
var url = 'https://www.google.com/movies/about/';
if (url.indexOf('movies') > -1) { 
   console.log('URL contains movies');
}
```

Example: condition not met; nothing will some up in console.

```js
var url = 'https://www.google.com/about/';
if (url.indexOf('movies') > -1) { 
   console.log('URL contains movies');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I just tried this solution. My feed currently just doesn't show when I implement this... could you explain further what 'String.indexOf()' does? Could you show a scenario URL where 'movies' condition would work and not work?

Comment: Thanks, so I got that working... only problem, what if I want to write multiple if statements like this, and then I already have 1 URL defined as var url? How could I write multiple with this solution, and multiple URL checks?

Comment: @CamC., there are several ways: `switch()`, `if else if else`, or a custom object that each `keyword` will represent a function to be called upon matching--this one is a bit cleaner in terms of code organization, but you might not into duplicates with matches pointing to same URL.

Comment: @CamC., you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Your answer helps a lot - but it doesn't solve the first part of my problem. 'I am trying to simply display a RSS feed only if the user is on a certain page' - with your solution I have to include 1 URL to be checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133726/discussion-between-adam-azad-and-cam-c).